# Why do c preprocessor directives ignore the \ newline rule when it is followed directly after a #?

Tags: c-preprocessor

Normally, via the standards, any \ followed directly by a newline is converted into the code without the newline and backslash. For example:

```
int yams\
yams;
```

turns into

```
int yamsyams;
```

and

```
int cheese // blerg \
more blerg
```

turns into

```
int cheese // blerg more blerg
```

This behavior can be nice with very long single line code.

However, it seems that

```
#\
This code not part of the macro
```

While

```
#a\
This code is part of the macro.
```

And even

```
#        \
This code is not part of the macro
```

While

```
#    a\
This code is part of the macro
```

Why is this the one exception to the "\ newline" being removed rule?

Comment: This is for readability. If you end up having lengthy code in a single line you could use '\' to move it to new line and still have the same functionality.

Comment: Agreed with the functionality in general, it is nice. I'm just wondering why # \ is the one exception to this rule.

Comment: Preprocessor has nothing to do with compilation. It is separated task. And probably it has its own rules.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question. I'm just wondering what those rules are in this specific case.

Comment: check this  - http://ideone.com/ftfYcV . it throws error for the case you mentioned.

Comment: You don't have any macros in your examples, those are preprocessor directives, but not macros.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little new to the terminology here. The question is now fixed.

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c1a7b55923fe049

Comment: When a macro parameter is used with a leading ‘#’, the preprocessor replaces it with the literal text of the actual argument, converted to a string constant. Unlike normal parameter replacement, the argument is not macro-expanded first. This is called stringification. Please refer to https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html#Stringification for more details

Comment: On a related sidenote, how should "\r" affect these rules if, say, we have "\r\\" instead? Or does the preprocessor just remove all "\r\r\r\n\\" 's that are at the end of the line? And what about "\ra\r\n\\"

Comment: @AramAntonyan, the question has nothing to do with macro arguments or stringification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in [[lex.phases]](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.phases), replacing the backslash-newline is done by the preprocessor, and should happen very early, in phase 2, which is before splitting the source into preprocessor tokens (phase 3) and before handling preprocessor directives such as `#define` or `#include` (phase 4).

So in all your examples you should see the backslash-newline removed.

Comment: So why does it not remove it in the case of

"# \\\n"
blerg?

Comment: It does. How are you establishing that it doesn't do it?

Comment: Awesome, testing it with code shows that it does actually remove the newline as expected. I was trusting notepad++ color highliting to be correct but I suppose that was higher expectations that I should have. That does mean that notepad++ has a bug, however.

Comment: @DanielleEnsign, do never completely trust editor's syntax highlight